# circular effect on slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider, carousel

does anyone know of an existing jquery plugin that I can use to achieve this effect?

I need images to overlap cycle through in a circular fashion and change the zoom.

[image]

Comment: can u provide an snippet so that we can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this one: http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel/

**Simple demo from the page:**

JavaScript

```
...
<!-- note: should work with jQuery 1.4 and up -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
      // include options like this:
      // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
      // option: value,
      // option: value
    });
  });
</script>
...
```

CSS

```
...
<style type="text/css">
  #carousel {
    width:800px;
    height: 300px;
    display: relative;
  }
  #carousel img {
    display: hidden; /* hide images until carousel prepares them */
    cursor: pointer; /* not needed if you wrap carousel items in links */
  }
</style>
...
```

HTML

```
...
<div id="carousel">
<img src="/image1.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
<img src="/image2.jpg" alt="Image 2" />
<img src="/image3.jpg" alt="Image 3" />
<img src="/image4.jpg" alt="Image 4" />
<img src="/image5.jpg" alt="Image 5" />
</div>
...
```

Comment: FYI: This plugin is not mobile friendly at all so this won't work if you're planning to use it for a tablet or mobile phone website.